# How to stop this after function in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a Stopwatch program and whenever i run it pressing the button , the function  def watch()  keeps executing itself and i cant stop it when needed.

is there any way to stop the execution of def watch() function after pressing the button?

Thanking you...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

tog = 0

hour = 0
mins = 0
sec = 0


def toggle():
    global tog
    tog = tog + 1

    if tog == 1:
        watch()
    elif tog == 2:
        stop()
        tog = 0

def stop():
    donothing = 0

def watch():
    global sec
    global hour
    global mins

    sec = sec + 1
    l1.config(text=sec)
    l1.after(1000,watch)



    l1 = Label(root)
    l1.pack()

Button(root,text="Start",command= lambda: toggle()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a reference to the `after` call, and cancel the callback when `toggle` is `False`. You can avoid ugly `global` declarations by using `tkinter` variables that are objects whose value can be read or set.

```
import tkinter as tk


def toggle_on_off():
    toggle.set(not toggle.get())
    if toggle.get():
        watch()

def watch():
    count_seconds.set(count_seconds.get() + 1)
    if toggle.get():
        _callback_id.set(root.after(1000, watch))
    else:
        root.after_cancel(_callback_id.get())
        
root = tk.Tk()

count_seconds = tk.IntVar(root)
count_seconds.set(0)
toggle = tk.BooleanVar(root)
toggle.set(False)

Button(root,text="Start",command=toggle_on_off).pack()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=count_seconds)
label.pack()

_callback_id = tk.StringVar(root)
_callback_id.set(None)

root.mainloop()
```

[Edit]

#### The same code with globals is like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def toggle_on_off():
    global toggle
    toggle = not toggle
    if toggle:
        watch()

def watch():
    global count_seconds, _callback_id
    count_seconds += 1
    label.configure(text=str(count_seconds))
    if toggle:
        _callback_id = root.after(1000, watch)
    else:
        root.after_cancel(_callback_id)
        
root = tk.Tk()

count_seconds = 0
toggle = False

Button(root,text="Start",command=toggle_on_off).pack()
label = tk.Label(root, text=str(count_seconds))
label.pack()

_callback_id = None

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code looks little confusing actually I am a new python coder so using globals are quite easier to me .. By the way thanks for your time

Comment: ok @Bittu, I understand. I added a version with globals. Keep both, staring at the code until you understand it will go a long way to improve your programing abilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable , for eaxmple "exit",

and add an if statement before l1.after(1000,watch)

```
def toggle():
    global tog, exit
    exit = False
    tog = tog + 1

    if tog == 1:
        watch()
    elif tog == 2:
        stop()
        tog = 0


def watch():
    global sec
    global hour
    global mins
    global exit

    sec = sec + 1
    l1.config(text=sec)
    if not exit:
        l1.after(1000,watch)
```

in stop(), you can write

```
def stop():
    global exit
    exit = True
```